# FastMap size > 0 but only one element

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, maps

I use FastMap `shared()` in a multithread service. Sometimes map crash. It show `size > 1`, but when I try get an element I get `null`. I always get only element at first position and other elements is `null`. I try get `value()` but also get only one element and `size > 1`.

Any solution? or maybe use other map?

About service: on map I hold connected to socket users. Several thread can read or write to map. I need thread safe map. FastMap work perfect until crash. It crash at random time. It can work 1 week or 1 hour.

Comment: If you find `null` in any `Map` it is not always an error. Many `Map` implementations are able to handle `null`.

Comment: i get size() value 4. but in map only 1 element. I put one more element. get size 5 but still only one element. I remove 2 elements and get size 3 but still 1 element. I create new FastMap and then it works but this is not good. I cant recreate map

Comment: You mention the word "crash" but I suspect it throws an exception.  Please provide the full exception that you are seeing.

Comment: My english is bad. I dont know how to say. There is no error or crash or exceptions only bad values and good size. When i get bad values in debug mode i try all types of map. atomic, shared, plain, values() also try new ArrayList(values()). All show good size and only one value. Looks like map locked old value and do not show new only size changed.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes map crash. It show size > 1, but when I try get an element I get null.

To really answer this question, you are going to have to provide more details about the problem and probably provide some code samples.  Specifically, you should provide an exceptions that you are seeing.

One possible problem is that although you are using `new FastMap<Foo, Bar>().shared()` it is very important to realize that this doesn't fully protect you from race conditions in your code.  If you are doing something like the following, then it would explain what you are seeing:

```
// even though this shows stuff in the map
if (map.size() > 0) {
    // by the time we get here, it might have been removed so this throws
    entry = map.entrySet().iterator().next();
}
```

Your code needs to take into consideration that multiple threads are (I assume) adding and removing from the map so if you are doing two operations on the map, the state of the map might have changed between them.

Hope this helps.  If you add more details to your question, we should be able to provide more specific help.

Comment: I dont user map like your example. i alsmot always use map.values() and sometimes user map.get(key) or map.replace(key, object). there is no errors only wrong map values. I use map.shared(). When client connect to socket i create new Thread. I get first command and create new client info object and try replace it in map. As key I use unique client id because cant connect 2 connections single client.

Comment: My example was just that, an example.  You need to worry about _any_ time that you have multiple calls to the map.  If you do more than 1 then race conditions exist @cezarius.